# Connect and obtain metadata from org

Tags: metadata, manifest

I'm told to obtain page layout or record type metadata. Also I was told that the so called manifest is the clue to this task.
What I managed to do is to connect to my org and that is all, after that I started to search on the internet for some guide.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a one-off you could use the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) to retrieve the metadata. If you need to do it programmatically you have various choices, ranging from using the [sfdx CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) (if you are scripting the metadata retrieval) to using the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_layout.htm) (if you are writing code to automate the retrieval).

It basically comes down to just what your use case is.